# Can you send letters to Azkaban prisoners?

Tags: harry-potter

If you want to communicate with a convict in there, can you send them a letter with an owl? Would Dementors give it to them?

Comment: Snuffles was ignored by the dementors so why not?  Owls are no less cool.

Comment: Yes, but only the letter Q, in whatever volume you wish.

Comment: You can probably send the letter successfully. Whether they're officially sanctioned or not, and whether or not your recipient will be of sound mind, is less clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Unknown but highly unlikely.**

Azkaban was known as a place of despair and misery where the prisoners frequently went insane and died there.

> ... Rowle carried out his plan and soon a steady trickle of prisoners had been placed there. None ever emerged. If they were not mad and dangerous before being placed in Azkaban, they swiftly became so.
>
> ... Prisoners were mostly insane and a graveyard had been established to accommodate those that died of despair.
>
> <sub>[Azkaban by J.K. Rowling on Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/azkaban)</sub>

Prisoners who so far gone into those depths on despair and insanity are likely not going to even realize who is writing to them. Nor would I expect the guards to want their prisoners feeling any type of hope. *Hope is a dangerous thing...*